# If a function from set $A$ to $B$ is one-to-one, is the function from $P(A)$ to $P(B)$ one-to-one as well?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $f$ is a function from set $A$ to set $B$, define the function $S_f$ from $2^A$ to $2^B$ by

$$S_f(X) = f(X)$$

for each subset $X$ of $A$.

If a function $f$ from set $A$ to $B$ is one-to-one, is the function from $P(A)$ to $P(B)$ one-to-one as well? What about onto?

How do I prove or disprove this? I would think that the function of the powersets would have the same correspondence as the function of the normal sets.

Comment: Yes, both are true. The easiest way to prove this seems to be directly from the relevant definitions.

Answer (score 3):

This is true. If $f\colon A\to B$ is injective, then $S_f(X)=f(X)$ is injective as a function from $\mathcal P(A)$ to $\mathcal P(B)$.

To prove this, verify the definition of "injective", namely take $X$ and $Y$ which are different and show that $f(X)\neq f(Y)$.

**HINT:** Suppose that $x\in X$ and $x\notin Y$, can $f(x)$ be an element of $f(Y)$?

For the second part, the proof is similar. We verify the definition of "onto", namely if $Y\subseteq B$, then there is some $X\subseteq A$ such that $f(X)=Y$. I'll leave you to think what sort of $X$ we can take here, but remember that we have to resort to the assumption that $f$ is onto, at some point in the proof.